# Golden Arrows with Union

Tags: sql, sapb1

I have a query in SAP B1 (SQL) where i have used UNION ALL to combine data from three tables. I have set it up as a universal function in Boyum's B1 Usability Package, but don't know how to get the golden arrows working via the format wizard on the T0.[DocNum] column due to three sources. Can anybody please help?

```
SELECT T0.[DocDate], T0.[DocNum], T0.[CardCode], T0.[CardName], T0.[DocTotal], T0.[VatSum]
FROM ODPI T0
WHERE T0.DocDate>='[%0]' and T0.DocDate<='[%1]'

UNION ALL

SELECT T0.[DocDate], T0.[DocNum], T0.[CardCode], T0.[CardName], T0.[DocTotal], T0.[VatSum]
FROM OINV T0
WHERE T0.DocDate>='[%0]' and T0.DocDate<='[%1]'

UNION ALL

SELECT T0.[DocDate], T0.[DocNum], T0.[CardCode], T0.[CardName], -1 * T0 [DocTotal], -1 * T0.[VatSum]
FROM ORIN T0
WHERE T0.DocDate>='[%0]' and T0.DocDate<='[%1]'
```

Comment: I'm not sure it'll work with UNIONs because it won't be able to tell what the source Table is for that particular row.

Comment: And when you say "set it up as a universal function", do you mean that you're using Boyum's B1 Usability Package? You may be able to get it to work with that...

Comment: Hi Zac. Yes we are using B1 Usability Package. How do i set it up with that?

Comment: In the Wizard, each has its own unique type even with DocEntry - "OINV_ENTRY", "ORIN_ENTRY" , "ODPI_ENTRY" so how can I use them or am I looking in the wrong spot?

Comment: Are you saying that you've given each table it's own unique DocEntry column? E.g. `SELECT T0.DocEntry as OINV_Entry, null as ORIN_Entry, null as ODPI_Entry ... FROM OINV T0 UNION ALL SELECT null as OINV_Entry, T0.DocEntry as ORIN_Entry, null as ODPI_Entry ... FROM ORIN T0 UNION ALL ... FROM ODPI ...`? Because then, yeah, you could just specify the Object Type in the Format field using the Wizard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the fact that you're using Boyum's B1 Usability Package, you can take advantage of their SQL Report Universal Function to get the right Object Types associated with the columns.

You'd need to split out the DocNums for the different source tables into different columns, so that you can apply the types to the right columns.

The query you'd use for that is something like this:

```
SELECT T0.[DocDate], T0.DocNum AS ODPI_DocNum, null as OINV_DocNum, null as ORIN_DocNum, T0.[DocNum], T0.[CardCode], T0.[CardName], T0.[DocTotal], T0.[VatSum]
FROM ODPI T0
WHERE T0.DocDate>='[%0]' and T0.DocDate<='[%1]'

UNION ALL

SELECT T0.[DocDate], null AS ODPI_DocNum, T0.DocNum as OINV_DocNum, null as ORIN_DocNum, T0.[DocNum], T0.[CardCode], T0.[CardName], T0.[DocTotal], T0.[VatSum]
FROM OINV T0
WHERE T0.DocDate>='[%0]' and T0.DocDate<='[%1]'

UNION ALL

SELECT T0.[DocDate], null AS ODPI_DocNum, null as OINV_DocNum, T0.DocNum as ORIN_DocNum, T0.[DocNum], T0.[CardCode], T0.[CardName], -1 * T0.[DocTotal], -1 * T0.[VatSum]
FROM ORIN T0
WHERE T0.DocDate>='[%0]' and T0.DocDate<='[%1]'
```

The below image shows you how you'd need to set up the Universal Function, specifically the Format field:
[image]